# Cannot delete records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models: Project, team and users.

Team has many projects associated.

In my projects def I want to delete teams associated to projects but nothing happens when I click delete.

My destroy def is as follows:

```
def destroy
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @team = project.team
  @project.destroy
  # edit #1 shown below:
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @team, notice: 'Project was successfully destroyed.' }
  end
end
```

And making the button inside show.erb.html to delete project and link back to project path

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Project', project_path(@project), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure'}, method: :destroy, class:'button is-danger is-outlined' %>
                        </div>
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :projects
  resources :teams
  as :user do
    put '/user/confirmation' => 'confirmations#update', :via => :patch, :as => :update_user_confirmation
  end



   devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: 'registrations',
    confirmations: 'confirmations'
  }
  devise_scope :user do  
    get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'     
  end
  root 'home#index'
end
```

I'm still very new to rails and cannot find a reason for why this may be occuring.

### Edit 2 - More details

Projects Controller is as follows:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /projects
  # GET /projects.json
  def index
    @projects = Project.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  # GET /projects/1
  # GET /projects/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /projects/new
  def new
    @project = current_user.projects.build
    @teams = Team.where('id = ?', current_user.team_id)
  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
    @teams = current_user.teams
  end

  # POST /projects
  # POST /projects.json
  def create
    @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /projects/1
  # DELETE /projects/1.json
  def destroy
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @team = project.team
    @project.destroy
    # edit #1 shown below:
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @team, notice: 'Project was successfully destroyed.' }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, :team_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: do you get an error of any kind? You are are trying to delete the project, not the team associated with it and you are also trying to redirect to the project you just destroyed. Try looking up `dependent: :destroy` on the rails association docs.

Comment: Try [`@project.destroy!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-destroy-21), that will raise an exception if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting to a resource after you delete it doesn't work, because that resource no longer exists. So the controller action should probably redirect to the deleted projects team:

```
def destroy
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @team = project.team
  @project.destroy
  # edit #1 shown below:
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @team, notice: 'Project was successfully destroyed.' }
  end
end
```

Then your `link_to` should use `method: :delete`, **NOT** `method: :destroy`:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Project', project_path(@project), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure'}, method: :delete, class:'button is-danger is-outlined' %>
```

Ref: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to-label-Options

See if that gets you going, and if not please share some debugging information.

**Edit #1:**
In your controllers destroy action, you need to do a little more work to handle how rails responds to requests. I didn't notice it missing before but the action should have a `respond_to` block where you can choose to respond different ways basically. I modified the above controller action code to give you an example.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ben, I've changed these two points, unfortunately, I get no error (I've tried @project.destroy! as someone else suggested but no error), I'm receiving a GET request when I click the delete button, so I'm wondering if it something to do with my routes?  I've included my routes up above.
```
started GET "/projects/1" for ::1 at 2019-12-08 11:09:26 +1300
```

Comment: @basic Are you sure your terminal/bash isn't showing any errors? The puma server should be outputting feedback there on any database queries made, and errors that crop up every time a request is made.  
  
Also, can you add in your whole project controllers code(just the project controller, not all controllers in your project)?  

BTW I just noticed something else you need to change. See my answer edit.

Comment: Definitely no errors coming up. Just seems to be reloading as I hit the delete button. I've just added the project controller up in my original post and have made that change you have stated in your post.

Comment: Sounds like it's not picking up the method of the link_to for some reason, and so it just renders the show action probably. what's the output of the `rails routes` command?  
Also, you really need to figure out how to share the output from your rails server that shows the requests being made. There's no obvious error I'm seeing at the moment, and we need to know what's happening when the request is made. I can't help you unless you get that.  
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html